# Iteration over a list of dictionaries with for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, types

In my code I'm trying to iterate over a list of dictionaries and use the values of those dictionaries to create new objects.
The problem is that apparently when I write the for loop, instead than iterating over the dictionaries it seems to iterate directly over the elements inside the first dictionary, and I don't really understand why!

This is the code:

```
class Phase:

    def __init__(self, workshop, machining, operator, placings):

        self.workshop = workshop
        self.machining = machining
        self.operator = operator
        self.placings = placings


class Part:

    def __init__(self, name, phases):

        self.name = name
        self.phases = phases


class Loader:

    def __init__(self, cycles_file, workshops_file):

        self.cycles_file = cycles_file
        self.workshops_file = workshops_file
        self.workshops = []


cycles = {'part1': [{'workshop': 'ws1', 'machining': 10, 'operator': 0, 'placings': 2},
                    {'workshop': 'ws2', 'machining': 7, 'operator': 3, 'placings': 0}],
          'part2': {'workshop': 'ws3', 'machining': 5, 'operator': 5, 'placings': 0}}

parts = []
for part in cycles:
    print('part: ', part)
    name = part
    phases = []
    print('cycle: ', cycles[part], type(cycles[part]))
    for phase in cycles[part]:
        print('phase: ', phase, type(phase))
        workshop = phase.get('workshop')
        machining = phase.get('machining')
        operator = phase.get('operator')
        placings = phase.get('placings')
        phase = Phase(workshop, machining, operator, placings)
        phases.append(phase)
    part = Part(name, phases)
    parts.append(part)

workshops = {'ws1': {'turns': 3, 'turn duration': 8},
             'ws2': {'turns': 2, 'turn duration': 7.5},
             'ws3': {'turns': 2, 'turn duration': 7.5}}

loader = Loader(cycles, workshops)
```

And this is the result I get:

```
part:  part1

cycle:  [{'workshop': 'ws1', 'machining': 10, 'operator': 0, 'placings': 2}, {'workshop': 'ws2', 
  'machining': 7, 'operator': 3, 'placings': 0}] 
<class 'list'>
 
phase:  {'workshop': 'ws1', 'machining': 10, 'operator': 0, 'placings': 2} 
<class 'dict'>

phase:  {'workshop': 'ws2', 'machining': 7, 'operator': 3, 'placings': 0}
<class 'dict'>

part:  part2

cycle:  {'workshop': 'ws3', 'machining': 5, 'operator': 5, 'placings': 0} 
<class 'dict'>
 
phase:  workshop <class 'str'>

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\logistic_management_tool\try2.py", line 42, in <module>
     workshop = phase.get('workshop')
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The problem here is that phase should be a dict, as it is before entering the for loop!

Comment: Which list of dictionaries are you talking about?  Could you maybe come up with a smaller example that demonstrates the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is that the phases of part2 are not defined as a list, hence the second iteration of the *"internal"* loop is trying to iterate over the keys of the *"internal"* dictionary.

Try adding a pair of square brackets around the dict, like so

```
cycles = {'part1': [{'workshop': 'ws1', 'machining': 10, 'operator': 0, 'placings': 2},
                    {'workshop': 'ws2', 'machining': 7, 'operator': 3, 'placings': 0}],
          'part2': [{'workshop': 'ws3', 'machining': 5, 'operator': 5, 'placings': 0}]}
          #        ^                                                                 ^
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I just noticed sorry! Thanks anyways